# Show different fields when adding a content depends on the language

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

i have a question about a multilanguage feature which i don't find. I have contenttype with many fields (about 20 fields). Now i want to translate this page in a few languages. My problem is that some fields (the content of the fields) are only visible for a specific language like italian for example.

So the first idea could be to add additional fields to the contenttype for the specific languages. In aspect to the code i would render the specific field depending of what language is selected on the page.

But in relating of adding a content this could be very confusing with many languages.

So my question is: Is it possible to show fields when adding a content depending on what language is selected for the new content. For example when i have a field which should only visible for the italian translation.

Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some specific fields which only should be viewed based on language , the best way to do that is by using [page manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) and [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) .

1. Download and enable this modules
2. go to Structure -> pages
3. enable node_view
4. add a variant and select Selection Rules
5. now add a rule based on user->language and node->type
6. and now you can make a custom view based on language

Comment: Ok that sounds good. The main problem in my opinion is the confusing backend page (when adding the content) with all the fields. I will try your solution

Comment: in this case "node_edit" option of page manager can help. hope that works

Comment: i think your answer is the solution. Just one question: As mentioned above i have many fields. In the overview were i can the fields which i want to show, is there a way to select all and then diselect the fields which are language specific. Cause now i must add all things like the submit buttons, the publish option etc.. individual. And sorry that i can't upvote your answer

Comment: I hope this will help a bit : https://drupalize.me/videos/quickly-duplicating-variants-cloning?p=1137
not to import all fields very fast but at least you can use what you have done now in the future.

Comment: i have another question. On the pages overview where all the pages with url are listed (for example the Url: /node/%node/edit). How can i add the /node/add/%node Url to the list? Cause when i try to add this Url it always said that the Url is already in use. I can't get it to work. Is this Url possible to add?

Comment: check if this works : https://www.drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier for you to have only one field that you would be translated with the appropriate function : `t()`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7

You may then translate it directly via the code or with the translation interface in the admin menu.